# How to change the color of Menu in material-ui

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I am using Menu from `material-ui` and want to change the background color. Problem is, when I give color to Menu, it changes the whole page background when the menu popper appears. And when I apply color to Menu Items, it leaves some grey shades at the top and bottom, because all these menu Items are enclosed inside a div. 
Problem Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-dropdown-background-color-g88e1

What's the right way to change Menu's background color?

I tried `createMuiTheme` for changing this, but it changes the color of all the Menus in my application. I want to apply this style to only one of the Menu Items. So looking for a solution to do this using `makeStyle`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are multiple ways

#### 1.Material-UI [Menu CSS API](https://material-ui.com/api/menu/#css)

we have the API called **paper**

> Global class: `.MuiMenu-paper`
>   Description: Styles applied to the Paper component.

```
<Menu
  ...
  classes={{ paper: classes.menuPaper }}
>
```

```
export const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) => ({
  menuPaper: {
    backgroundColor: "lightblue"
  }
}));
```

#### 2.Use Material-UI [nesting selector](https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/#nesting-selectors) to directly select the `MuiPaper-root`

An optional way for some cases when there is no related CSS API exposed.

```
<Menu
  ...
  className={classes.menu}
>
```

```
export const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) => ({
  menu: {
    "& .MuiPaper-root": {
      backgroundColor: "lightblue"
    }
  }
}));
```

---

[image]

---

You can check the DOM structure to find out which element's className should you use

```
<div
  class="MuiPaper-root MuiMenu-paper MuiPopover-paper MuiPaper-elevation8 MuiPaper-rounded"
  tabindex="-1"
  style="opacity: 1; transform: none; transition: opacity 251ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 0ms, transform 167ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 0ms; top: 16px; left: 16px; transform-origin: -8px 10px;"
>
  <ul>
    <li />
    <li />
    <li />
  </ul>
</div>;
```

Here the `MuiPaper-root` appears to be the first. So use it would be fine.

Comment: It seems  `@mui/styles` (which provides the function `makeStyles` is now deprecated though :( (https://mui.com/styles/basics/#hook-api)

Answer (score 2):

An update for MUI v5 using createTheme(). Add the `&[role="menu"]` selector to only target lists in the Menu component.

```
const theme = createTheme({
      components: {
        MuiMenu: {
          styleOverrides: {
            list: {
              '&[role="menu"]': {
              backgroundColor: '#2196f3'
              },
            },
          },
        },
      },
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to add Mui class in sx prop, Just like this:

```html
<Menu sx={
    { mt: "1px", "& .MuiMenu-paper": 
      { backgroundColor: "black", }, 
    }
  }>
</Menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is also a css fix, if you call the main root and color the ul only.

```
.MuiMenu-root ul{
  background-color: white;
  color: #0F4D81;
}
```