# Material UI MenuItem override ListItem classes

Tags: material-ui

I am trying to override the style of  MenuItem when hover and selected.
To my understanding, the solution is certainly using makeStyles to create customized classes.

```
 <MenuIte
            classes={{ root: classes.menuItem ,selected:classes.menuItemSelected }}

          >
            {"SomeText"}
          </MenuItem>
```

```
export default makeStyles(theme => ({
   menuItemSelected: {
        "&:hover": {
            backgroundColor: "#4868cf",
            color: "white",
        }
    },
    menuItem: {
        fontSize: 12,
        paddingTop: "4px",
        paddingBottom: "4px",
        "&:hover, &:focus": {
            backgroundColor: "#4868cf",
            color: "white",
        }
    }
}));
```

However my customized classes is overrided by the .MuiListItem-root.Mui-selected

[image]

So, I understand the priority is directly related to the specificity. 
My question is how can i add more specificity using the makestyle customized class in this case.
codesandbox

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-jnzw7

Comment: In latest version v4.9.9, there is a "ListItemClasses" props that i can use to fix this problem. But what can i do for older version ?

Comment: @keikai, i dont think it is the answer. Using selector give me control over classes -> MuiMenuItem. I want to get rid of MuiListItem which is recognized as having higher specificity in the case

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/61023885/11872246

Comment: @keikai thx for help. Probably the best way is just create a styled component on my own.

Answer (score 0):

```
export default makeStyles(theme => ({
   menuItemSelected: {
        "&:hover": {
            backgroundColor: "#4868cf",
            color: "white",
        }
    },
    menuItem: {
        fontSize: 12,
        paddingTop: "4px",
        paddingBottom: "4px",
        "&:hover, &:focus": {
            backgroundColor: "#4868cf",
            color: "white",
        }
    }
}), { name 'SimpleListMenu' });
```

You need to give a name.

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-t7589

You can read out https://material-ui.com/styles/advanced/#with-material-ui-core