# .Muimenu-root is not working | Menu MUI component | styled-cocmponent

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I like to apply styled to the root level with `Menu` component from MUI.
I also use `styled-components`

```
import * as React from "react";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import MenuItem from "@mui/material/MenuItem";
import { MenuRaw } from "./styles";

export default function BasicMenu() {
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);
  const open = Boolean(anchorEl);
  const handleClick = (event) => {
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
  };
  const handleClose = () => {
    setAnchorEl(null);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Button
        id="basic-button"
        aria-controls={open ? "basic-menu" : undefined}
        aria-haspopup="true"
        aria-expanded={open ? "true" : undefined}
        onClick={handleClick}
      >
        Dashboard
      </Button>
      <MenuRaw
        id="basic-menu"
        anchorEl={anchorEl}
        open={open}
        onClose={handleClose}
        MenuListProps={{
          "aria-labelledby": "basic-button"
        }}
      >
        <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Profile</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>My account</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Logout</MenuItem>
      </MenuRaw>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
import styled from "styled-components";
import Menu from "@mui/material/Menu";

export const MenuRaw = styled(Menu)`
  width: 412px;

  .Muimenu-root {
    background-color: pink;
    .MuiMenu-paper {
      background-color: pink;
    }
  }
`;
```

I tried multiple ways but how can I change the width of the menu?

I changed the menu's width by having css width in the `MenuItem` component. Does anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a helpful link to your question ! it has already been answered :D 
[Change the color Menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61023797/how-to-change-the-color-of-menu-in-material-ui)

Comment: Thanks for the link but I already tried that and that is talking about `MenuItem` not `Menu`. So I can add style to `MenuItem` (which is Profile, My account and Logout) but not the paper wall behind the items